# Set default xaml window background image in dll

Tags: wpf, xaml, dll, uri

I am currently developing a default WPF control Kit. 
But I am stuck with using the correct kind of uri in xaml.

What I have is an image wich should be used as the background for the non-client area of my window. 
To make the default controls available very easy I want to put everything in a dll. 
Other apps can quickly reference that dll and get access to the style.

The problem is, that my image is not showing up when using the dll style in an app.

My image (/Resources/WindowBackground.jpg) is set to Resource and I am using the following xaml:

```
<Image Grid.ColumnSpan="99" Grid.RowSpan="99">
   <Image.OpacityMask>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/WindowBackground.jpg"/>
   </Image.OpacityMask>
</Image>
```

I also tried:

```
<Image Grid.ColumnSpan="99" Grid.RowSpan="99" Source="/Resources/WindowBackground.jpg"/>
```

Both write the following into the output (Couple times):
..."System.IO.IOException" in PresentationFramework.dll...

I also tried lots of other uris wich sometimes lead to XamlParseExeptions and other not so nice stuff.

Thank you for any hints :D

Comment: Try using this path: `pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Resources/WindowBackground.jpg`.

Comment: Nice try, But it cannot find the file during compile time. The filepath (wich cannot be found) displayed in the output  is correct.

Comment: It works after compiling 4 times. Write this as the answer and I will accept it:) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your answer in the [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. For your particular situation, you can use the following syntax to reference your resource image file:

```
pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Resources/WindowBackground.‌​jpg
```

From the linked page:

> The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that is located in a subfolder of the referenced assembly's project folder.
>
> pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml

Note: The type of resource file here is irrelevant.